# Is it possible to have a confirmationDialog on SwiftUI Menu?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode13

I've seen an app that uses [Menu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu) where when you press the a button, I'm asked to "confirm". This brought me to refactor my app:

```swift
@State var confirmDeletion: Bool = false

VStack {

    Button(role: .destructive) {
        self.confirmDeletion = true
    } label: {
        Spacer()
        
        Text("Delete")
        
        Spacer()
    }.confirmationDialog(
        "Are you sure?",
        isPresented: $confirmDeletion,
        titleVisibility: .visible
    ) {
        Button("Yes", role: .destructive) {
    
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Task {
                    
                    await doSomeAsynWork()
                }
            }
        }
        
        Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
    }
}
```

This works great. Now to refactor using Menu:

```swift
Menu {
    [..] // other buttons

    Button(role: .destructive) {
        print("I was called... and that's it")
        self.confirmDeletion = true
        
    } label: {
        Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
    }.confirmationDialog(
        "Are you sure?",
        isPresented: $confirmDeletion,
        titleVisibility: .visible
    ) {
        Button("Yes", role: .destructive) {
     
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Task {
                    
                    await doSomeAsynWork()
                }
            }
        }
        
        Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
    }
   
} label: {
    Label("Menu", systemImage: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle")
}
```

I understand that when you press any menu button, it closes straight away so that's why the `confirmationDialog` does not work. Could I achieve a `confirmationDialog` with Menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move it outside of `Menu`, like

```
Menu {
    [..] // other buttons

    Button(role: .destructive) {
        print("I was called... and that's it")
        self.confirmDeletion = true
        
    } label: {
        Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
    }
   
} label: {
    Label("Menu", systemImage: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle")
}
.confirmationDialog(                    // << here !!
        "Are you sure?",
        isPresented: $confirmDeletion,
        titleVisibility: .visible
    ) {
        Button("Yes", role: .destructive) {
     
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Task {
                    
                    await doSomeAsynWork()
                }
            }
        }
        
        Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
    }
```

Comment: This works! But _why_ does this work — what does moving the `confirmationDialog` outside of the `Menu` change?

Comment: When it's inside the menu, the menu disappears as soon as you tap the button, so the confirmation has nothing to anchor to.  Placing it outside of the menu gives it a persistent place to anchor